# recall value in regular expression

Tags: regex, unix, sed

I have the following regular expression working in sed but I want to retain a value. I want to retain the anchor text value. In this case it is a 3. Right now the below would output [] anywhere there is an anchor tag with href that has a pound sign in it. I want it to be [3] instead of []. The number is dynamic so in this case it is 3 but in it will be different every time. Anyway to get that number and then recall it in the regular expression?

```
echo '<a href="#anchor3">3</a>' | sed 's:<a href="#.*>[0-9]</a>:[]:g'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use capturing brackets and a backreference.

Capturing brackets are just brackets about the part of the pattern you wish to keep. You can then call them back in the replacement by using `\1` (for the first set of brackets), `\2`, etc.

```
echo '<a href="#anchor3">3</a>' | sed -r 's:<a href="#.*>([0-9])</a>:[\1]:g'

# returns '[3]'
```

Comment: I get an error...sed: 1: "s:<a href="#.*>([0-9])< ...": \1 not defined in the RE...also what is the r flag for sed?  I don't have that flag available to me. I tried it again without -r but still same error. I'm on a mac in a bash shell.

Comment: I installed ssed using MacPorts and changing sed to ssed and using your command above works perfectly. Thanks so much.

Comment: Hmm - I'm on linux in a bash shell. The '-r' means to enable extended regular expressions (i.e. I can do `.+([0-9])` instead of `.\+\([0-9]\)`. However, I don't think you can use backreferences without the `-r` switch, I'll have to investigate.

Comment: I've had a look at the man page for Mac's `sed` (it never occurred to me it would be different from a unix one) -- I think if you use the '-E' switch that will achieve the same effect ("extended regular expressions").

Comment: For reference, `-r` and `-E` are both nonstandard extensions. The former is GNU syntax and the latter is BSD syntax. The BSD syntax actually makes more sense because it corresponds to the `-E` switch to `grep`, which is standard.